# MongoDB Order by two columns

Tags: mongodb, tornado, pymongo

Does someone know how can I sort my tables by two values?

For example :

I have stats collections that has columns "_id", "title", "link", "stats", "range". 
"stats" column could consist values ['duration','pace', 'distance'], 
"range" column could consist velues like 0-10 km, 20-20 min so on depend of stats values.

I'd like to order by stats and after that by range .

[This link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqdnz2zl02t9z7p/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-17%20at%201.01.15%20PM.png)

In link above I've sorted by stats and now I want to sort by range for each value of stats!

My current code :

```
guides = yield gen.Task(Guides.objects.find, query={}, limit=20,
                            sort={'stats': 1})
```

Comment: Could you add your current query?

Comment: I think James' answer below about covers it :)

Answer (score 0):

To order your documents by more than one field, you would need a compound sort statement and ideally a compound index backing it.

For compound indexes in MongoDB see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/

Your sort would look something like:

```
guides = yield gen.Task(Guides.objects.find, query={}, limit=20,
                        sort={'stats': 1, 'range': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something that is ordered, in this case tuples of arrays, like:

```
sort([("stats",pymongo.ASCENDING), ("range",pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

Since, of course, python dicts are not ordered. That should work I believe.